# Place pdf_tex images side by side

Tags: graphics, pdftex, import

I am trying to import two pdf_tex files into my thesis which I will like to either place side by side or scale. However, I have tried \begin{subfigure}, \sf, both which have failed to place both files side by side. I successfully invoked \svgscale to scale the image, but the text refuses to scale with. Can anyone help out?

I am writing using writeLaTeX (overleaf.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the text separately by changing the `\fontsize`. However you will have to experiment with the exact value and maybe adjust some text positions in the  `.pdf_tex` file.

```
\begin{figure}
    \fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont
    \def\svgwidth{.48\textwidth}
    \input{bla.pdf_tex}
    \hfill
    \input{blub.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks. The \fontsize works flawlessly. However the \hfill seems not to help much. 
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont
   \def\svgscale{0.5}
  \import{./Figures/blahblah/}{summer.pdf_tex}\caption{the longitudinal resistance}\label{fig:longResistance}
   \hfill
   \def\svgscale{0.5}
   \import{./Figures/Ebeam/HallBar/}{RefMid_Rxysf.pdf_tex}
   \caption{the Hall resistance}\label{fig:hallResistance}\label{fig:poiuds}
\end{figure}                                                                                           This does not place the images side by side

Comment: @DeleOnipede Please edit your question. In an comment things as line breaks are lost. And please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) complete with `documentclass` and the necessary packages.

Comment: @DeleOnipede try with less than 0.5. Taking into account spaces etc. 0.5 is too big to fit two images side by side.

Comment: thanks once again. I have solved it. I discovered I placed a caption before call the next file. It's clear now. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

> Try to split the figure into two / multiple minipage and import / input your pdf_tex file in it.

`\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
        \def\svgwidth{1.0\textwidth}
        \import{Chapters/folder/Pictures/}{Pic1_a.pdf_tex}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
        \def\svgwidth{1.0\textwidth}
        \import{Chapters/folder/Pictures/}{Pic2_b.pdf_tex}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}`